# How to completely disable spellcheck on a page?

Tags: contextmenu, spell-checking, disable

I want to completely disable the spellcheck features of all browsers on specific (at least) inputs.

The context:
I am developing a spelling learning game where users (primary students) are taught spelling and they have to type in words. If they can use the spelling check of the browser, that defeats the purpose of the game.

I already apply `spellcheck="false"` on the inputs but the command is still available in the context menu.
I don't want to block the context menu as it may be useful to some users.

Is there any way to block the access to this feature? I guess it might be different from one browser to another.

Thanks for your help.
Ben

Comment: You may also want to add `autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"` to your inputs. And as for your context menu, you seem unsure what to do with it, but either you do block it or you don't. There's no in between.

Comment: I don't want to block access to the context menu, it would be too much just to avoid users to access one single feature. Especially when users could maybe give a keyboard shortcut to the spellcheck feature and so bypass the context menu. It's just this specific feature of spell checking I want to block.